# Setting up FTP user in iis 7

Tags: iis-7, ftp

I'm trying to set up an FTP user in iis7 and I've run into difficulty as I've never dealth with iis before.

FTP is all set up on the windows 2008 server, and an FTP site has been created with the ftproot folder. Within this folder there is Local Users with user accounts which are all associated with logon accounts to the server.

What I need to do is create an FTP user which won't have a windows logon account. This user will simple have their own directory on the server which they can connect and upload to.  I've looked up articles from the microsoft iis website but because I'm new to this I'm having a bit of trouble understanding them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using the IIS FTP service, it uses Windows accounts for access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider looking at Filezilla's FTP server. It runs under Windows and does not require tight integration to/with Windows' user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use the IIS User Manager, you need to create individual users in the IIS User manager, than you grant each of them authorization and access to the FTP Site.
You can also grant each user it's own home directory, and isolate each.